# How can I add conditional profile fields (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, profile

I would like to have conditional fields, that will be visible when certain conditions are met, for example:

New Customer, IF group is business, show business address field, IF group is individual, show home address, etc..

I am using WordPress 5.2.1 and CiviCRM 5.4.0

Answer (score 5):

Welcome Ashok, you could explore using this extension https://civicrm.org/extensions/profile-conditionals

The other option would be to use the caldera webforms plugin which has an integration with civicrm. Caldera has support for conditionals. 
https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm